# Horizontal Form - Best way to set width of a control label?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to twitter bootstrap and I'm working with a horizontal form.  My code is something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="whatever">Whatever</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="whatever" name="whatever">
                <option value="blah">Blah</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="another">Another</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="something" name="something">
                <option value="MyEntry">MyEntry</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

When I do this the form looks fine.  The only problem is the length of the control-label is way too long so I get a lot of whitespace to the left of the labels.  Is there a way to shorten the label so I don't get as much whitespace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did it by creating couple of extra form classes and use them depending on the size I need.

This is my css:

```
.form-small .control-label {
    width: 100px;
}

.form-small .controls {
    margin-left: 120px;
}

.form-medium .control-label {
    width: 180px;
}

.form-medium .controls {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.form-xlarge .control-label {
    width: 240px;
}

.form-xlarge .controls {
    margin-left: 260px;
}
```

So if I need small label:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-small">

<!-- form body -->

</form>
```

Of course you can setup your own `.control-label` and `.controls` widths according to your needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome.  This worked.  I tried adding my own class specifically for the control label itself and it wasn't working.  I have no idea why.  Doing it this way worked great.  Maybe it was some stupid CSS cache issue or something weird.

Comment: Very nice solution! I've adapted the widths for me and it's worked very fine, thanks!

Comment: How does hard-coding the sizes work on mobile and tablets?  Seems like this would break bootstrap's responsiveness.

Comment: @Acyra for mobile support you should go for media queries and use `width: 100%` with them

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline" 
    ng-submit="addCategory(transaction, categoryText)" 
    style='display:inline;'>
    <span class="span2">
        <label style='display:inline; width:140px'>{{param}}</label>
    </span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="categoryText" size="20" placeholder="add category">
</form>
```

I usually span the element in need for fixed size in a "span" element but this is for generating repeated forms

Answer (score 0):

Try using  to create a container:

```
<div class="set_inline_block_class_selector">
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="example_radio">Bootstrap radio button with controlled label
 </label>
</div>

<style>
 .set_inline_block_class_selector label{
     display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```